# How do to refine how to select key for hash?

Tags: ruby

So, I'm trying to patch a class to allow it to be used for a hash key.  However, I can't seem to get it to work.  Here is an example test case:

```
class Tmp
 def hash; rand(); end
end

module Patch
 refine Tmp do
  def hash; 1; end
  def eql?(rhs); hash == rhs.hash; end
 end
end

puts "=========================="
module A
 # Using the initial implementation of Tmp
 x = {}
 x[Tmp.new] = 1
 x[Tmp.new] = 2
 puts "#{Tmp.new.hash == Tmp.new.hash}"
 puts "#{Tmp.new.eql? Tmp.new}"
 puts "#{x}"
end

puts "=========================="
module A
 # Enabling the refinement of class Tmp here
 using Patch
 x = {}
 x[Tmp.new] = 1
 x[Tmp.new] = 2
 puts "#{Tmp.new.hash == Tmp.new.hash}"
 puts "#{Tmp.new.eql? Tmp.new}"
 puts "#{x}"
end
```

This gives the result:

```
==========================
false
false
{#<Tmp:0x0000407e4ae818>=>1, #<Tmp:0x0000407e4ae7a0>=>2}
==========================
true
true
{#<Tmp:0x0000407e4ae188>=>1, #<Tmp:0x0000407e4ae110>=>2}
```

As you can see, the `#eql?` and `#hash` methods work as expected, but when I try and use it as a hash key, it thinks that they are different keys.  What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

As an aside, the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-Hash+Keys) state:

> Two objects refer to the same hash key **when their hash value is identical *and* the two objects are eql? to each other.**
>
> A user-defined class may be used as a hash key if the hash and eql? methods are overridden to provide meaningful behavior.

(Emphasis mine)

It's interesting that that only `#eql?` seems to be used to determine key equality:

```
class Tmp
 def hash; rand; end
 def eql?(rhs); true; end
end

puts "=========================="
module A
 x = {}
 x[Tmp.new] = 1
 x[Tmp.new] = 2
 puts "#{Tmp.new.hash == Tmp.new.hash}"
 puts "#{Tmp.new.eql? Tmp.new}"
 puts "#{x}"
end
```

Gives:

```
==========================
false
true
{#<Tmp:0x0000407e407b08>=>2}
```

The return value of `#hash` isn't relevant:

```
class Tmp
 def hash; 1; end
 def eql?(rhs); false; end
end

puts "=========================="
module A
 x = {}
 x[Tmp.new] = 1
 x[Tmp.new] = 2
 puts "#{Tmp.new.hash == Tmp.new.hash}"
 puts "#{Tmp.new.eql? Tmp.new}"
 puts "#{x}"
end
```

Gives:

```
==========================
true
false
{#<Tmp:0x0000407e40e408>=>1, #<Tmp:0x0000407e40e3b8>=>2}
```

Which seems to contradict the docs.  Is this an artifact of using ruby v2.2.4?  (I'm using ruby that comes with Sketchup 2017)

Comment: Note: Having a random `hash` value is going to cause problems. It needs to return the same value each time it's called on the same object storing the same data.

Comment: @tadman I used `rand` only for example purposes.  I wouldn't do that normally.

Comment: Yeah, just trying to figure out the intent here.

Comment: After reading this several times I'm still not sure what the question is. That last example works as expected, you've forced them to not be `eql?` so you get two separate keys.

Comment: @tadman, yes, but I would expect that the 2nd last example should also have the same results as the last example as `#hash` doesn't give a constant value, even if `#eql?` gives `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing your class with clearly inconsistent behaviour. For any object where `a.eql?(b)` then by definition `a.hash == b.hash` as `#hash` must reflect the object's actual contents. If it doesn't you will get very odd results.

It's like how when writing a sort comparator if `a < b` and `b < c` then `a < c` *must* be true. If for some reason this is not true then your sorting operations will produce very strange and inconsistent results.

In other words:

- `a.eql?(b)` *must* be true if and only if `a` and `b` represent the same thing.
- `a.hash == b.hash` *must* be true if `a` and `b` represent the same thing.

Note that `a.hash == b.hash` does not mean they are necessarily the same thing, but it indicates a high probability that they are. A secondary check with `eql?` is always necessary to confirm this.

The Hash internals may or may not call both of these functions. At small sizes the Ruby "Hash" isn't a hash table at all, it's just a tiny array. As such, `#hash` might not even be called until the table reaches a certain size and that method is relevant.

Comment: You seen to be missing the point. The last half (after the edit) was shooting findings that were inconsistent with the docs, namely that `#eql?` *and* `#hash` need to be true.  Given that, *both* of the examples shown should have each object be considered as a different key. Also, that was an aside. Just before the *Edit*  states the actual question. To be clear, why *isn't* the refinement being used for the hash key, but *is* when using the methods directly.

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully emphasize the appropriate points.

Comment: I'm not sure refinements are going to work here as it's `Hash` itself calling those methods, which is outside of the scope of the refinement.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised that.  The `using` is limited to the scope of the module or class that I use it in, and only from that point on till the close of that  module or class block.  Seems to be the same with `#to_s` when auto converting to a string.  Unfortunate. :(

Comment: Yeah, it's extremely localized in effect and doesn't impact other source files.